# Como almacenar y gestionar contenido multimedia en un sistema web?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, aplicación-web, nosql

mi problema es el siguiente: tengo una coleccion de informacion de tipo imagenes, audios, videos, documentos escanedos y documentos en formato de texto, los cuales poseen varias clasificaciones por su tipo y fecha. Necesito hacer un sistema (preferiblemente web) que gestione esto, adicione y elimine contenido, arealice busquedas con diversos parametros etc. Mi pregunta es, para este tipo de contenido entiendo que existen varias alternativas para almacenar y gestionar esto, bases de datos NoSQL, SQL. Cual podria ser la mejor alternativa para el almacenamiento de este tipo de informacion? teniendo en cuenta que el volumen de informacion es de alrededor de 8000 imagenes.

Comment: Podrias probar un servidor de archivos y almacenar únicamente las urls en las bases de datos (S3 de Amazon, por ejemplo)

Comment: Necesito utilizar un servicio local, ya que no dispongo de conexión a internet en el lugar donde voy a montar este servidor

Answer (score 0):

Si solo quieres almacenar imagenes, video y documentos bien te puede servir un almacenamiento por Blob o Blob Storage.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/storage-for-media-services/

tienes accesibiladad por web y su precio por almacenamiento es barato digo ya depende
de la cantidad de espacio que contrates.

Ahora de manera funcional lo manejas como cuando manejas  archivos en Windows.

Tienes una Cuenta ---> Creas un repositorio --> y el repositorio almacena los  archivos

De manera manual o por codigo puedes manejar el tipo de accesso al elemento,
digo puedes enviarle al usuario una url para que vea o descargue el archivo, y a ese link
le das una ventana de tiempo para ser accessible, digamos link disponible solo por un dia,semana, mes, permanente.

Puedes crear una cuenta en Azure de manera gratuita y con almacenamiento limitado pero
te servira para hacer pruebas.

Ejemplo:
https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/using-.net-to-access-blob-storage-with-microsoft-azure.html

Ahora en el Blob el Archivo lo guardas por nombre,es decir comou un sistema de archivo para informacion adicional, puedes usar SQL para guardar mas informacion acerca del archivo, ruta del archivo
o si tiene relacion con algun usuario o modulo de tu sistema.

saludos.

Comment: Es una buena idea, pero mi intención es montar este servidor en un lugar donde no hay acceso a internet, por lo que Azure no me es viable